# Significant differences between F# and Clojure

Tags: clojure, f#, functional-programming

What are the most significant differences between the F# and Clojure ?

Which constructs has F# which Clojure does not have and vice  versa?

Does F# have macros?

Answer (score 61):

Most of the differences will stem from the fact that F# is descended from [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_programming_language) while clojure is descended from [lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_programming_languag).

So F# has a more ML/OCaml/Haskell feel with emphasis on:

- static typing
- type inference
- pattern matching

While clojure has more of a Lisp feel with emphasis on:

- s-expressions
- macros
- closures

Also as Brian noted, F# is a .Net language while clojure is a JVM language so each will have access to a vast but different set of libraries.

Comment: There is ClojureCLR, in Clojure/contrib, but it's alpha at the moment.

Comment: clojure supports some lazy stuff and F# is a strict language

Comment: Also, Clojure has a great STM implementation. F#'s computation expressions (for monadic syntax) and quotations overlap with macros a bit.

Comment: F# has lazy sequences more or less like Clojure's. Where I'd draw the distinction is with Clojure's built-in persistent data structures & emphasis on STM.

Comment: They both have sophisticated mechanisms to interact with object types. Those could be libraries or C#, Java code respectively.

Answer (score 11):

Clojure is a lisp, actualy lisp-1 family language. F# is practicaly OCaml adopted to .net platform.

Answer (score 8):

One key difference is that F# is a .NET language, whereas Clojure runs on a JVM. Thus the deployments and supported platforms will be different.

Note that F# is supported by mono, however.

As for macros, I think [you're out of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88302/macro-support-in-f).

Comment: And AFAIK there exists no platform that would run .NET but wouldn't run JVM. The other way round, there are many cases. So, Clojure is more generic while F# is more or less Microsoft specific.

Comment: @mad-j Yeah well. Mono fills much of that multi-platform space for .NET. And, the vanilla JVM does not run on android, for example. So Java is more or less Sun-specific?

Comment: Hardly. Common on Windows/Linux/Mac for instance.

Comment: @Joonas - iPhone and iPad run .NET via MonoTouch but do not support Java. That is a pretty big hole.

Comment: @Justin: Seems that someone is hacking Java support into iThings regardless of Apple's political decisions: http://www.jroller.com/neugens/entry/running_pure_java_applications_on

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there's some effort being put into running Clojure on the CLR. Looks very promising.

http://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr

Answer (score 3):

They are both [functional first](https://vimeo.com/68226717) programming languages, but their type systems are very different. F# is a strongly typed language and Clojure is a dynamically typed language and so

1. Boumbles' answer to What is the [Difference between Strong vs.
   Static Typing AND Weak vs. Dynamic
   Typing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11889763/575530);
2. haylem's answer to [Dynamically vs Statically typed languages
   studies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12381/50096); or
3. Joey Adams's question [What is better for prototyping: a
   statically-typed language, or a dynamically-typed
   one?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/105846/50096)

may help answer "what are the most significant differences between the F# and Clojure?". Note however that the debate between "static typing" and "dynamic typing" is a long running one and so can appear religious.

Answer (score 2):

F# really corresponds to Scala on JVM. The closest thing to Clojure on .NET platform is IronScheme.

Comment: "F# really corresponds to Scala". Technically but not politically. Scala is an academic language whereas F# and Clojure are industrial languages.

Comment: @Jon - not sure it is fair to describe Scala as an academic language. It has a lot of "pragmatic" features, has good Java platform interop and I've seen it being used in big enterprises (e.g. banks) more than either F# or Clojure so far.

Comment: @mikera: Well, Scala became more of an industrial language when Martin Odersky founded TypeSafe the year after I wrote that comment. Scala's UK job market share increased 10x since then. http://www.itjobswatch.co.uk/jobs/uk/scala.do

Answer (score 2):

If you want macros, you can use it with [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) or [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/).