# Functional languages compatible with Mono

Tags: mono, functional-programming

Is F# the only actively-developed functional language for the CLI, which supports Mono and has Monodevelop plug-in? or are there others I missed?

F# is pretty fun, but it's not as awesome as a lisp like clojure which sadly doesn't support mono yet.

Comment: C# has a lot of functional language features too.  It is procedural at heart, but it's not too tricky to create a functional API for it.

Comment: I forgot to add, my idea of "fun" is writing very clean, very concise code. I doubt hacked up C# will cut it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [macro support in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88302/macro-support-in-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [IronScheme](http://IronScheme.CodePlex.Com/), [Clojure](http://Clojure.Org/) (or more precisely [ClojureCLR](https://GitHub.Com/RichHickey/Clojure-CLR/wiki/)) and [Nemerle](http://Nemerle.Org/). The CLI port of [Scala](http://Scala-Lang.Org/) picked up steam again a couple of months ago and is even sponsored by Microsoft, although AFAIR the projected feature-parity release (i.e. the point at which the JVM and CLI versions have the samne features and are released on the same day) is 3.0, which is still one or two years away.

Comment: Useful pointers. I was unable, however, to compile ClojureCLR under mono, and cannot find examples of anybody else who has.